# How can I get the params of joinPoint.proceed() result in AspectJ?

Tags: java, aspectj

I have the following advice code:

```
    @Around("annotatedMethod()")
    public Object aroundGetPanel(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable    
    {       
    Object result = joinPoint.proceed();        
    return result;
    }
```

And the method who executes the above method is:

```
    public Person getPerson(String id){
          return new Person(1,"Maialen");
    }

    public class Person {
        private Integer id = null;
        private String name = null;
        public Person(Integer id,String name){
            this.setId(id);
            this.setName(name);
        }
        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return nombre;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```

How can I get the params of object result (Person)? 
Using reflection? Using annotations?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered how to do it via reflection:

```
    Class<?> clazz = result.getClass();
    Field field = org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.findField(clazz, "name");
    org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
    String name=field.get(result).toString();
```

But I prefer do it by annotations. Is there a mode?